# Problem referencing nodes directly when using XPath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I've recently hit a wall with an issue with Java's native XML API (the W3C one) which at its core is that if I try to use a direct XPath expression in my document like, say, `//body` the XPath is evaluated as false *(incorrect behaviour)*, however if I replace that with `//*[1]` it evaluates as true *(desired behaviour)*.

I have checked numerous times and with different documents that the XML I use is valid (*I'm using mainly XHTML 2.0 with rest of this system*).

Since I have no idea what really causes this, here's the set of configuration options for various factory objects I'm using.

As you can see, I have lots of custom implementations of various classes related to the whole issue which I think may have something to do with the issue but I'm not sure, running around with unit tests, playing with debugger and a huge load of .println:s hasn't helped me yet.

**XPath:**

- `xpathfactory.setXPathFunctionResolver(myFunctionResolver)`
- `xpath.setNamespaceContext(myNamespaceContext);`
- `xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(myResolver);`

**DocumentBuilder:**

*(f  == DocumentBuilderFactory)*

- `f.f.setValidating(false);`
- `f.setSchema(null);`
- `f.setNamespaceAware(true);`
- `f.setIgnoringComments(true);`
- `f.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);`
- +features `"http://xml.org/sax/features/validation"`, `"http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema"` and `"http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd"` as `false`

*(dc == DocumentBuilder)*

- `dc.setEntityResolver(null);`
- `dc.setErrorHandler(myErrorHandler);`

Also worth mentioning is that I'm using Sun Java 5 on Windows XP.

All ideas are welcome at this point, I'm getting quite frustrated because of this issue.

### Conclusion

It was a namespace issue, the problem was that I didn't declare *default* namespace in myNamespaceContext at all! Just by adding

```
else {
    return "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
}
```

made the thing work and now I made it so that default namespace is detected. Works like a charm! Both answers helped me to find the cause and I'd select both as preferred answer if I could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not familiar with java, but that sounds for all the world like a namespace problem - presumably the default namespace of the document and the evaluator are different.

edit: can we see your xml doc and code? And how does `//*[local-name()='body']` respond?

Comment: The xml doc is basically just a Hello World version of simplest possible XHTML document (I can't unfortunately provide actual doc since it contains disclosed material). The xpath expression you gave works just like //*[1], that is it evaluates as expected and returns true.

Comment: definitely a namespace issue then - find a way to provide that to your evaluator

Answer (score 3):

If it's XHTML then it'll have a [namespace](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/) defined. You either remove that (not necessarily advisable), or qualify your expression thus:

```
//:body
```

(note the leading colon which qualifies the above)`enter code here`

Comment: Throws "com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: "